# How to add footer and header while printing multiple pages in adobe air?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air, flex4

I need to print a datagrid ,It has huge data to print..so I need to include header and footer in every page..
How to add footer and header while printing multiple pages in adobe air?

Answer (score 0):

You can only print what your view represents, you'll have to add the header and footers before you issue the command to print.

Mayb alive PDF can offer a solution: http://alivepdf.bytearray.org/
More in particular: [Custom header and footer](http://indepthflex.wordpress.com/2011/02/16/alive-pdf-custom-header-footer/)